# Distance between empirical measures and thickened version

Tags: hilbert-spaces, gaussian, geometric-probability, optimal-transportation, wasserstein-distance

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $x_1,...,x_n$ be points in $\mathcal{H}$.  Let  $\varepsilon >0 $ be given and consider the  measures
$$
\mu := \frac1{n}\,\sum_{i=1}^n\, \delta_{x_i} \mbox{ and } 
\mu^{\varepsilon} := \frac1{n}\,\sum_{i=1}^n\, G(x_i,\varepsilon\, T).
$$
Here $T$ is any trace-class operator on $\mathcal{H}$ and $G(x,\Sigma) $ denotes the Gaussian measure on $\mathcal{H}$ with mean $x$ and covariance operator $\Sigma$.

Is there an upper bound on the 2-Wasserstein distance between $\mu$ and $\mu^{\varepsilon}$ that depends only on $\varepsilon$ and tends to 0 as $\varepsilon$ does?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Fair enough, I have replace $\epsilon I$ with $\epsilon T$ for an arbitrary trace-class operator on $X$.

Comment: Then the claim follows by a synchronous coupling: $X = x_I$ and $X^{\epsilon} = x_I + \sqrt{\epsilon} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  \sqrt{\lambda_j} e_j$ where $I \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(\{1, \dots, n \})$; $e_j$ are the eigenfunctions of $T$; and $\lambda_j$ are the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Wait what is $x_I$?

Comment: I am using your notation $P(x_I = x_j) = 1/n$ for $j \in \{1, \dots, n \}$.  It is basically a uniformly randomly selected element of the set $\{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Ah okay.  Still I have trouble seeing why; could I ask for a bit more detail?

Comment: Indeed, \begin{align*}
\mathcal{W}_2(\mu,\mu^{\epsilon})^2 \le E\left[ |X - X^{\epsilon} |^2 \right] = \epsilon E\left[| \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  \sqrt{\lambda_j} e_j|^2 \right] = \epsilon \operatorname{trace}(T) \;. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah okok now its rather clear.  Actually obvious.  Thanks Nawaf!

Comment: There was an omission in my comments above, so I just posted the correction in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim follows by a synchronous coupling: $X = x_I$ and $X^{\epsilon} = x_I + \sqrt{\epsilon} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}   \sqrt{\lambda_j} \rho_j e_j$ where $I \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(\{1, \dots, n \})$; $e_j$ are the eigenfunctions of $T$; $\lambda_j$ are the corresponding eigenvalues; and $\{ \rho_j \} \overset{i.i.d}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Indeed, \begin{align*}
\mathcal{W}_2(\mu,\mu^{\epsilon})^2 \le E\left[ |X - X^{\epsilon} |^2 \right] = \epsilon E\left[| \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  \sqrt{\lambda_j} \rho_j e_j|^2 \right] = \epsilon \operatorname{trace}(T) \;. 
\end{align*}